# Trying to add tap gesture to UILabel inside of UITableView - tap gesture not being called

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer, didselectrowatindexpath

I've seen the other examples/questions asked on SO in regards to the topic but I cannot get mine to work.

I have a custom table view cell, to which I have added a label. The user is to be able to touch the label in order to change its colour. However when I tap the label it calls `didSelectCellAtIndexPath` and does not register the tap.

I would like the label to get priority, therefore if the label is pressed it is to change the colour and not call `didSelectCellAtIndexPath`.

But if I select an area outside of the label then it is to act like a normal cell and call `didSelectCellAtIndexPath`.

Here is my custom cell:

```
@implementation CustomTableViewCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code

    self.backgroundLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,150)];
    self.overLayLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,150)];
    self.nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160,150)];

    [self insertSubview:self.backgroundLabel atIndex:0];
    [self insertSubview:self.overLayLabel atIndex:1];
    [self insertSubview:self.nameLabel atIndex:2]; 


    self.selectFavColour = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270, 0, 60, 60)];
    self.selectFavColour.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    self.selectFavColour.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    [self insertSubview:self.selectFavColour atIndex:3];

    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


    UITapGestureRecognizer * tapPress = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapPress:)];
    tapPress.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
    tapPress.delegate=self;
    tapPress.delaysTouchesBegan=YES;
    tapPress.cancelsTouchesInView=YES;
    [self.selectFavColour addGestureRecognizer:tapPress];
}
    return self;
}



-(void)tapPress: (UIGestureRecognizer*) tap{

    NSLog(@"Tap press");

}
```

Comment: wy you are inserting at index 3 `[self insertSubview:self.selectFavColour atIndex:3];` just add it to content view `[self.contentView addsubview:self.selectFavColour];` and check weather method is calling or not and also make sure that there is no other view's on top of `self.selectFavColour`

Comment: Sorry I omitted that I have an image at Index 1 and and Image at index 2, that is why it is at Index 3. I will update the question

Comment: wy are u using the `self.backgroundLabel `  and `self.overLayLabel ` with same frame and also if possible post the screen shot how u want to display the labels in cell

Comment: come to chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49117/ios-help

Comment: @Shan backgroundLabel is a solid colour, and overlayLabel is set to alpha 0.5

Comment: i am getting the call back when tapped on the `self.selectFavColour`

Comment: come to chat chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49117/ios-help

Comment: @Shan I will double check my code

Comment: i copyied and past it to my example project and it is working

Comment: come to this link http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49117/ios-help

Comment: @Shan you were right I just had to  '[self.contentView addSubview:self.selectFavColour];' and it worked, please post as answer and I will accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try by adding it to `contentView`, for any view that u are adding to table cell add it to cell's `contentView`

for example

```
    [self.contentView insertSubview:self.backgroundLabel atIndex:0];
    [self.contentView insertSubview:self.overLayLabel atIndex:1];
    [self.contentView insertSubview:self.nameLabel atIndex:2];
    [self.contentView insertSubview:self.selectFavColour atIndex:3];
```

hope this helps u